# Hover function for this html using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have the following code:

```
<div class="portfolio">
    <a href="#" ><i></i>
        <span>
            <strong>douras.co</strong>
        </span>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="portfolio">
    <a href="#"><i></i></a>
</div>
<div class="portfolio">
    <a href="#"><i></i></a>
</div>
<div class="portfolio">
    <a href="#"><i></i></a>
</div>
<div class="portfolio">
    <a href="#"><i></i></a>
</div>
<div class="portfolio">
    <a href="#"><i></i></a>
</div>
<div class="portfolio">
    <a href="#"><i></i></a>
</div>
<div class="portfolio">
    <a href="#"><i></i></a>             
</div> 
<div class="portfolio">
    <a href="#"><i></i></a>
</div>
```

I want to give hover function to the span given inside the link and also I need to include span to all the links below for hover. So I need jQuery function for this. Given below are the links for each list.

Comment: What are you trying to acheive?

Comment: i want the script for hover function

Comment: and also i need to use span function only when mouse move over it

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, why did you name your edit *Corrected Spelling*, when you didn't correct any spelling? Please label your comments accurately, or this *could* lead to them getting rejected.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nnBK5/1/ is this you want? but what you want to achieve with this?

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
$(".portfolio a span").hover(function () {
  //your stuff here
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is function for `mouseover` and `mouseleave` function

```
$(".portfolio a span")
.mouseover(function () {
  //your stuff here
 })
.mouseleave(function () {
  //your stuff here
 });
```

Comment: mouseenter not mouseover!

Comment: @RakeshKumar mouseover doesn't bubble unlike mouseenter

Comment: stuff means??
iam just a beginner

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you are asking about.
Add a class to span like

```
 <span class="spanhover">
```

now in your css write

```
.spanhover:hover
{
// give the style
}
```

And in jquery try this:

```
  $(".spanhover").hover(function () {
  //your stuff here
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".portfolio a").each(function ()
{
    $(this).append('<span>Span text</span>');
});//this will add span to all links
$(".portfolio a span").on('mouseenter',function ()
{
    alert('Hover');
});//this will add hover function to span inside link
```

This should work

Comment: I have also given class to the span and strong

.portfolio span{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 33px;
    height: 170px;
    left: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 320px;

}
.portfolio span strong{
    display: block;
    padding: 56px 9px 5px 13px;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".portfolio a span").hover(
    function() {
        // Your code to run when your mouse enter the span
    }, function() {
        // Your code to run when your mouse leave the span
    }
);
```

Also, since you're beginner, I'd strongly recommend you to go through these tutorials from `jQuery` offical website here: https://learn.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

Hope you want something like [this](http://jsbin.com/folid/1/edit).

```
$(".portfolio a span").hover(function () {
  $(this).css('color','#FF0000');
},function () {
  $(this).css('color','#0000FF');
});
```

Comment: You should post code here when answering, not just a link.  (What would happen if jsbin were down when someone visited this page expecting answers?)

Comment: pasting only code and watching a live thing is different.

Comment: @PaulShan I never said "only code".  I specifically made a point of saying "not **just** a link".  You *need* to post code as well or this will be flagged as not being an answer and, quite rightly, get deleted.